# How do I search for files inside a directory, then burn the name of that directory into the files inside using ffmpeg?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I'm struggling to articulate this question- but I'm after a way of searching for files inside any directory that may exist in my search area (ie. not specifying the name of the directory), then using that directory name as a burn in on the files I have inside it, using ffmpeg?

So for example, say I had a folder with my script inside it. I've just created a folder called "day 01" inside the folder with the script, with some mxf files inside that. If I run my script, I want it to find the mxf files inside "day 01" then run ffmpeg and have that write "day 01" as a burn in on the picture of those mxf files.

I know how to do the burn in, I just don't know how to reference the directory "day 01".

Hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

method one of the many:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name '*.mxf' -print0 | while read -d $'\0' INP
do
  TXT="${INP%/*}"
  TXT="${TXT##*/}"
  echo "${INP} - ${TXT} - ${INP%.*}_txt.mp4"
  ffmpeg -i "$INP" -filter_complex "
drawtext=text='${TXT}':
fontsize=h/30:
x=(w-text_w)/2:
y=(h-text_h*2):
fontcolor=white[v]
" -map [v] -map 0:a -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 23 -c:a aac -q:a 4 "${INP%.*}_txt.mp4" -hide_banner -y < /dev/null
done
```